# external table in DB2

Tags: db2, odbc, ibm-cloud, db2-luw

I am trying to create an external table in DB2 warehouse in the cloud with the following command.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE EXT_5   (ID INT, AGE INT)
USING (DATAOBJECT ('abc.csv')
DELIMITER ','
MAXERRORS 10
SOCKETBUFSIZE 30000
REMOTESOURCE 'LOCAL')
```

The response to this query is a success. But getting an error as `unsupported client` when trying to insert/select rows to/from this external table.

Comment: Please provide more information: What client are you using, what plan (Entry, Enterprise, ...) are you using, how is the select done?

Answer (score 0):

EXTERNAL TABLEs require version 11.1.2.2 or above of the Db2 Client. 
E.g. see the line item "External table support by ODBC/CLI" here https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.wn.doc/doc/c0060895.html

You can download the latest version of your Client from here http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27016878

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I have one doubt. If creation of external table is successful, then why Db2 Client is required for insertion rows into that table. I am also able to drop that table. Trying to create external table with same name also throwing error as object is already there.

Comment: I am struggling to reproduce your error. Can you say what Client software you are using (or are you using the Db2WoC console)? What Db2 Warehouse on Cloud plan you are using (Entry?). Also do you have an error code and/or the full error message.